# Change ResxLocalizationProvider.DefaultDictionary in Codebehind

Tags: c#, wpf, localization

I am using http://wpflocalizeextension.codeplex.com for localization and have the following page.

```
<Window xmlns:lex="http://wpflocalizeextension.codeplex.com"
    lex:LocalizeDictionary.DesignCulture="en"
    lex:ResxLocalizationProvider.DefaultAssembly="AssemblyTestResourceLib"
    lex:ResxLocalizationProvider.DefaultDictionary="Strings">
 <!-- Some controls -->
 </Window>
```

Does anyone know how to Change the property in code behind ?

```
 ResxLocalizationProvider.DefaultDictionary="Strings"
```

ie to

```
 ResxLocalizationProvider.DefaultDictionary="OtherStrings"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that is an attached property, would it be something like

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Console.WriteLine(ResxLocalizationProvider.GetDefaultDictionary(this));
        ResxLocalizationProvider.SetDefaultDictionary(this, "OtherStrings");
        Console.WriteLine(ResxLocalizationProvider.GetDefaultDictionary(this));
    }
```

?

I don't actually have the lex module so can't try this out myself...

Comment: Hi ive just tried that and it doesnt work, it comes up with "Error  Non-invocable member 'WPFLocalizeExtension.Providers.ResxLocalizationProvider.DefaultDictionaryProperty' cannot be used like a method. "

Comment: Hi @WelshKing sorry - I got it slightly wrong, a "this" parameter is also needed by the SetDefaultDictionary method. I have now tested it in the Window constructor function and have modified the code above to show the test I did. This seems to work fine - the output shows the original value and the new value as required.